# Session timeout issues while executing Oracle stored procedures from QTP

Tags: oracle, session-timeout, qtp

We have automated the process of capturing baseline metrics of various queries as part of Oracle tuning project. The automation is carried out by a QTP script which executes the procedure, which in turn runs the query for specified number of times with different input parameters. Once the execution of stored procedure is complete, it opens OEM and saves the reports by searching the particular SQL ID.

We are facing an issue while running stored procedures which in turn has queries taking lot of time to execute. In such cases, the QTP executes the stored procedure for some duration of time and after that it appears to have been stopped. When I check OEM, after a certain  amount of time, QTP terminates the execution of stored procedures and the session seems to have been timed out.

Since QTP uses ADO, do I need to set “CommandTimeout” property of the connection to some large value in case of executing stored procedures which take lot of time? Doesn’t the QTP throw any error in case of any such time out issue? In our case the QTP status was still being displayed as “Running”, even when nothing was happening in the backend.

Comment: Could you post some code? Especially the call that should time-out in a cleanly manner? QTP does not use ADO. Your script might, and then it might be useful to see your script (or QTP function library) code so we can help you better.